# Почему происходит запись данных в таблицу из другой сессии, несмотря на то, что я установил блокировку чтения для таблицы?

Tags: mysql, сессия, mariadb

У меня есть таблица t, которая содержит два столбца: name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, surname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL

Я установил блокировку чтения в первой сессии с помощью следующего кода:

```
LOCK TABLE t READ;
```

Я попробовал записать данные вот так:

```
INSERT INTO t(name, surname) VALUES('Stan', 'Collins');
```

И сгенерировалась ошибка, в которой сказано, что таблица `t` была заблочена с помощью READ лока и не может быть обновлена. Все ок, так и должно быть.
Я перезашел в MySQL и попытался ввести данные в таблицу во второй раз, набрав код и по какой-то причине он заработал. Как я узнал из этой статьи https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/ когда READ лок установлен, сессия которая активировала его и остальные сессии могут читать, но не могут записывать данные в таблицу.

Так почему же данные были записаны в таблицу во второй сессии, несмотря на то, что я установил READ лок в первой сессии?

Comment: Меня насторожила фраза "_Я перезашел в MySQL_"... Как именно вы это сделали ? Случайно первая сессия (в которой lock) при этом не завершилась ?

Comment: Mike, завершилась. Да, поэтому и READ LOCK был сброшен. Я понял.

Comment: В статье было написано, что если сессия завершается нормально, или ненормально, то READ и WRITE локи будут сброшены. Так как я вышел из MySQL локи были сброшены. Теперь всё ясно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из-за пере захода в MySQL READ LOCK был сброшен. Поэтому  во второй сессии данные записываются в таблицу. Если же не выходить из MySQL, а запустить вторую сессию параллельно с первой, то данные не запиутся, MySQL перейдет в режим ожидания и будет находиться в нём пока не будет сброшен READ LOCK в первой сессии. Будь то явный сброс (через команду UNLOCK TABLES) или завершение сессии.